# How to add an image from a template form with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm studying JS and at the moment i'm not really good with it. I created a page (a kind of social network) and i need to add an image from an URL when i fill a form. The form has 2 fields: Image title and URL

the initial cards that i have on the page, i handle to insert them from an array. But i can't understand how to add a single photo from a form.

The new photo should appear as first image, the previous 1st image should be at the 2nd place and so on, cards can be deleted when i click on a button but i didn't really got how to do it, and the like buttons should work for every single cards... i've was looking for it on google and i found some stuffs but they didn't work for me.

how can i solve it?

my code:

```
HTML

      <section class="cards" id="cards">
            <!-- images will be added here-->
            <div class="cards__add-form-overlay">
              <form class="cards__add-form">
                <button class="cards__add-form-close-icon"></button>
                <p class="cards__add-form-text">New place</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="cards__add-form-first-field" id="ImageName" value= "">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Image URL" class="cards__add-form-second-field" id="URL" value= "">
                <button type="submit" class="cards__add-form-submit">create</button>
              </form>
            </div>
      </section>


  <template class="elements" id="elements">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="element__card">
        <img class="element__photo" src="" alt="">
          <div class="element__button-container">
            <button type="button" class="element__trash-button" id="trashbutton">
          </div>
      <div class="element__text">
        <p class="element__place"></p>
        <button type="button" class="element__like-button" id="likebutton" onclick="toggle()"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
JS
// IMAGES //
// description: adding photos in the page from an array with JS //

const initialCards = [
    { name:'', link:''}, 
    { name:'', link:''}, 
    { name:'', link:''}, 
    { name:'', link:''}, 
    { name:'', link:''}, 
    { name:'', link:''}    
];

initialCards.forEach(card => cardItem(card));

function cardItem(cardData) {
    const container = document.getElementById("cards");
    const cardTemplate = document.getElementById("elements").content;
    
    const newCard = cardTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    const elementImage = newCard.querySelector('.element__photo');
    const elementText = newCard.querySelector('.element__place');

    elementImage.src = cardData.link;
    elementText.textContent = cardData.name;
 
    container.append(newCard);
 }
----- Until here all good 

// description: adding popup when clicking on + button, and close with X button //

document.querySelector('.profile__add-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-overlay').style.visibility = 'visible';
});

document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-close-icon').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-overlay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-overlay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

document.querySelector('.profile__add-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.cards__add-form').style.visibility = 'visible';
});

document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-close-icon').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.cards__add-form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.cards__add-form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

// description: adding photo through popup with 2 fields, name and URL //

const addPhoto = document.querySelector('.cards__add-form');
const imageNameInput = document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-first-field');
const imageUrlInput = document.querySelector('.cards__add-form-first-field');

function handleAddCardFormSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  
    const element = createCard(imageNameInput.value, imageUrlInput.value);
  
    elements.prepend(element);
  
    imageNameInput.value = '';
    imageUrlInput.value = '';
  
    closePopup(evt.target.closest('.cards__add-form'));
  }

function createCard(name, link) {
    const elementTemplate = document.querySelector('#element-template').content;
    const element = elementTemplate.querySelector('.element').cloneNode(true);
    const elementImage = element.querySelector('.element__photo');
    const elementTitle = element.querySelector('.element__place');
    elementImage.src = link;
    elementTitle.textContent = name;
  
//like button//
    const likeButton = element.querySelector('.element__like-button');
  
    likeButton.addEventListener('click', () => likeButton.classList.toggle('element__like-button_active'));
  //delete cards //
    element.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      if (evt.target.classList.contains('element__trash-button')) {
        evt.currentTarget.remove();
      }
  
      if (evt.target.classList.contains('element__photo')) {
        openImagePopup(name, link);
      }
    });
  
    return element;
  }
  
  initialCards.forEach(({name, link}) => elements.append(createCard(name, link)));
```

with this code, the new image doesn't appear, about like button console says that toogle() is not defined, and delete button don't delete the image but no error in the console

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: i edit the post, now the code is shorter, now there are only the parts that could be useful to solve my problem